# How to exclude zero in a for loop in Java

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm trying to exclude the zero in this nested for loop here using != 0; but it is not doing anything. I'm trying to get the probability of each out come of 2 six sided dice when rolled. I must figure out the amount of times they are rolled first, but a die doesn't have a zero in it, so I must exclude it. I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

```
for( die2 = 0; die2 <= 6 && die2 != 0; die2++)
            for( die1 = 0; die1 <= 6 && die1 != 0; die1++)
                System.out.println("Die 2: " + (die2 * userInputValue) + " " + "Die 1: " +       (die1 * userInputValue));
```

Comment: Can you explain "it is not doing anything."? Are you seeing no printed output? Other than the obvious "don't start at zer0", what actually is your problem?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Note that "didn't work" does not help us to help you.  Copy/paste the error or output.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to this. I just discovered it and it's a god send, but I'm still getting the hang of it. My problem was that it wouldn't show any output for the nested loop. The terminal would be blank. But it's because I started my loop at 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your loops at 1, not at 0.

Let's look at your current code:

```
for (die2 = 0; die2 <= 6 && die2 != 0; die2++)
    for (die1 = 0; die1 <= 6 && die1 != 0; die1++)
        // Do something
```

Why aren't you hitting the do something line?  This chunk of code is equivalent(*) to

```
die2 = 0;
while (die2 <= 6 && die2 != 0) {
    die1 = 0;
    while (die1 <= 6 && die1 != 0) {
        // Do something
        die1++;
    }
    die2++;
}
```

Notice that the first condition check if `die2` is 0, but `die2` will *always* be 0 upon entering the loop because that's what you set.  Instead, you should use

```
for (die2 = 1; die2 <= 6; die2++)
    for (die1 = 1; die1 <= 6; die1++)
        // Do something
```

which will skip 0 because you never set `die2` or `die1` to 0 in the first place.

---

(*) This rewriting of a while loop isn't *exactly* equivalent to a for loop, because this rewriting doesn't preserve the semantics of the `continue` statement, but your code doesn't use continue, so in this case it's equivalent to the original.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a long day...haha

Answer (score 2):

Just start loop from `1` instead of `0`

```
for(int die2 = 1; die2 <= 6 ; die2++)
            for(int die1 = 1; die1 <= 6 ; die1++)
                System.out.println("Die 2: " + (die2 * userInputValue) + " " + "Die 1: " +       (die1 * userInputValue));
```

Comment: @user1745508: What do you mean, it didn't work. Are you getting any exceptions

Comment: I've been working on my school work for about 12 hours now and I'm getting programming block. I miss stupid stuff.

Comment: I was editing, may be you saw first version. Hope answered helped now.

Comment: Yeah, I used it too soon. It did help. Thank you very much.